# C: Use 8 bits of char for a full int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to convert the 8 bits of a char to the least significant bits of an int. I know that the conversion from `char` to `int` is easy doable via

```
int var = (int) var2;
```

where var2 is of type `char` (or even without putting `(int)`).

But I wonder, if I write the code above, are the remaining highest significant (32-8=) 24 bits of the `int` just random or are they set to 0?

Example: 
Let `var2` be `00001001`, if I write the code above, is `var` then `00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001`?

Comment: No. Remaining bits must be 00000000 00000000

Comment: signed char and Value is not the case when negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to convert the 8 bits of a char to the least significant
>   bits of an int

A `char` isn't guaranteed to be 8 bits. It might be more. Furthermore, as others have mentioned, it could be a signed integer type. Negative `char` values will convert to negative `int` values, in the following code.

> `int var = (int) var2;`

The sign bit is considered to be the most significant, so this code doesn't do what you want it to. Perhaps you mean to convert from `char` to `unsigned char` (to make it positive), and then to `int` (by implicit conversion):

```
int var = (unsigned char) var2;
```

If you foresee `CHAR_BIT` exceeding 8 in your use case scenarios, you might want to consider using the modulo operator to reduce it:

```
int var = (unsigned char) var2 % 256;
```

> But I wonder, if I write the code above, are the remaining highest
>   significant (32-8=) 24 bits of the int just random or are they set to
>   0?

Of course an assignment will assign *the entire* value, not just part of it.

> Example: Let var2 be 00001001, if I write the code above, is var then
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001?

Semantically, yes. The C standard requires that an `int` be able to store values between the range of -32767 and 32767. Your implementation may choose to represent larger ranges, but that's not required. Technically, an `int` is *at least 16 bits*. Just keep that in mind.

For values of `var2` that are negative, however (eg. `10000001` in binary notation), the sign bit will be extended. `var` will end up being `10000000 00000001` (in binary notation).

Answer (score 5):

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.5.4 Cast operators
>
> Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the value of the
>   expression to the named type.

Therefore, the remaining of `var` are set to 0.

By the way, the explicit cast is unecessary. The conversion from `char` to `int` is *implicit*.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
>   bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions.

Comment: Ok, and what about if I use pointers, e.g. something like `int var = *((int *) var2)`; does that hold also in that case?

Comment: @navititious: Your example leads to an *undefined behavior*, since it breaks the *strict aliasing rule*. An object that have `char` type shall be accessed with an lvalue that have `((un)signed) char` type. `int` is not allowed in that case.

Comment: this answer is incomplete, since it doesn't take into account the signed-ness of the `char` type (it's implementation defined), and ignores which signed representation is used (also implementation defined)

Comment: @Kirilenko ... unless it is suitable aligned to store an `int`, and the underlying representation doesn't form a trap.

Comment: @navige Do you realise that your question isn't correctly answered by this? Read the next answer...

Answer (score 2):

A C/C++ compiler can choose for the `char` type to be either signed or unsigned.

If your compiler defines `char` to be signed, the upper bits will be sign-extended when it is cast to an `int`. That is, they will either be all zeros or all ones depending on the value of the sign bit of `var2`. For example, if `var2` has the value `-1` (in hex, that's `0xff`), `var` will also be `-1` after the assignment (represented as `0xffffffff` on a 32-bit machine).

If your compiler defines `char` to be unsigned, the upper bits will be all zero. For example, if `var2` has the value `255` (again `0xff`), the value of `var` will be `255` (`0x000000ff`).

Answer (score 1):

For casting a `char` variable named `c` to an `int`:

- if `c` is a positive such as 24, then `c` = `00011000` and after casting it will be fill up by **zeros**:

  `00000000 00000000 00000000 00011000`
- if `c` is a negative such as -24, then `c` = `11101000` and after casting it will be fill up by **ones**:

  `11111111 11111111 11111111 11101000`

Comment: This assumes a 2's complement representation.